# Angular JS with Tridion 2013 SP1. Is it feasible?

Tags: 2013

We need to build a responsive website(desktop, mobile, tablet) and the client has a high preference to use Angular JS at the frontend. At the backend we have content in Tridion 2013 SP1 and App server boxes have Tomcat 7.0. Is it feasible  to combine Tridion and Angular JS. If yes, what will be the best approach to implement this? Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 10):

Is it possible? Yes, of course it is.

I would definitely recommend watching [this video](https://vimeo.com/142626199) from this year's Developer Summit, it's a great lecture on simplicity by Bjorn, the Master of making complex things look easy.

And [this article](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/client-side-templating-with-json-odata-and-angular) by Will Price is a good read on the subject too.

Comment: For in-context editing (Experience Manager), we've also seen setups with Angular JS. See this [TRex answer](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8403/46) and another post by [Will Price](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/edit-ajax-loaded-content-with-experience-manager-really), inspired by community member [Jaime Alcon](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com).